# Access Node Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How I can access an array node? For example, field "cantidad"?

Result:

```
Array ( 
  [2] => Array (
    [cantidad] => 1 
    [id_producto] => 2
    [precio] => 875
    [nombre] => Queso manchego
    [imagen] => dodgers01.jpg
    [btn_add_item] => Agregar al carrito 
  ) 
)
```

My code is:

```
<?php
$carritoactual = $this->carrito->get_carrito();
print_r($carritoactual);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking questions this basic, I suggest you start reading up on the PHP manual - for this question, the [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) page would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your array `$carritoactual` contains one item with the index `2`. The content of this element is itself an associative array.

You would refer to that array via its key (the index number) like this:

```
$carritoactual[2]
```

So if you want to print the content of that array:

```
print_r( $carritoactual[2] );
```

This is similar to what you did with the result of `$this->carrito->get_carrito();` but it directly accesses the element with its key (`2`).

Now if you want to access `cantidad`, which is one of the elements inside `$carritoactual[2]`:

```
print_r( $carritoactual[2]['cantidad'] );
```

Notice that the main array has a numerical key, but the second array has string keys. In PHP you can mix numerical and string keys.

Of course you should [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

This is an array rather than an object

```
$Variable[2]['cantidad'];
```

will get you the value you want.